# Удаление ненужных символов из pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня огромный объем данных (155000 текстовых комментариев). Для последующего обучения нужно убрать ненужные символы (#,&,XX/XXXX итд). Делаю я обработку данных с помощью следующей функции:

```
file = pd.read_csv('X_train.csv',sep = ',', parse_dates=['Date received'])

def preprocessor(text):
    l = len(text)
    for i in range(l):
        text[i] = text[i].lower()
        text[i] = re.sub("x{2}", " ", text[i])
        text[i] = rg.sub(r'[^\pL\p{Space}]', " ", text[i])

title = file['title']
preprocessor(title)
```

title - это столбец с комментариями (т.е. с текстом, который нужно будет в дальнейшем использовать в модели Машинного обучения).
Но выполняется это очень-очень долго.

Как можно ускорить процесс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод .replace вместо цикла:

```
df = pd.read_csv('X_train.csv',sep = ',')    
df = df.replace(to_replace ='[^\pL\p{Space}]', value = '', regex = True)
```

Если хотите работать с определенной колонкой, то:

```
df = df['title'].replace(to_replace ='[^\pL\p{Space}]', value = '', regex = True)
```

Comment: Под file что понимается?

Comment: Ваш DataFrame, который вы так назвали

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('X_train.csv',sep = ',')
file = df['title']
file.replace(to_replace ='[^\pL\p{Space}]', value = '', regex = True)
@Nikolay, так вот делал, не работает

Comment: Если у вас df, значит используйте df.replace(... Просто в коде, который вы привели, было написано file

Comment: Ни так ни так не работает, правильно что мне надо сначала обратиться к столбцу с текстом, а потом от него работать с replace? Просто я так пробовал и не получилось

Comment: Вам нужно обращаться ко всему датафрейму, если хотите удалить значения во всем датафрейме, или к конкретной колонке, если хотите удалить значение только в ней. Приведите пример кода, как вы пытаетесь использовать.

Comment: В комментарии выше делал привел, продублирую


df = pd.read_csv('X_train.csv',sep = ',')     file = df['title']      file.replace(to_replace ='[^\pL\p{Space}]', value = '', regex = True)

Обратился к колонке и получил ошибку

Comment: Я же говорил, что file писать не нужно, если ваш датафрейм называется по другому. Я дополнил код в своем ответе, посмотрите еще раз внимательнее